# displaying X number of items from a list

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have a List of Items that I want to print to the console for debugging but I only want to display 3 Items at one time but this is within a function so It needs to know where it left off so it can start from the next 3 items from the previous ones how could I accomplish this?

```
static void list(Boolean nextPage)
{
    static List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();
    //if(nextPage) display next page            
    Console.WriteLine("Press numbers 1 - 3 to display more info on an item or press 4 for next page...\r\n");
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Item item in _items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((count + 1) + ": Name: " + item.itemName + ", ");

        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(("4: Next Page");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your function non-static, add a variable to store the last item that you have displayed so far, use that variable to decide where to start the next listing, and advance that value by three each time that you go through the function.

Here is a rough approximation to how you can do it - this will probably not work as a copy-paste replacement of your function, but it should give you an idea of what to do:

```
int lastPosition;

void list(Boolean nextPage) {
    if(!nextPage) {
        lastPosition = 0;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press numbers 1 - 3 to display more info on an item or press 4 for next page...\r\n");
    foreach (Item item in _items.Skip(lastPosition).Take(3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine((count + 1) + ": Name: " + item.itemName + ", ");
    }
    lastPosition += 3;
    Console.WriteLine(("4: Next Page");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything created within the scope of a method is trashed when you exit it, unless you return a value toward whoever called the method.

So, you have two choices (or more, but here's two):

```
private static Item lastItem;
```

With this, you store inside your class the last item displayed and retrieve it the next time.
or

```
public static Item itemlist(Boolean nextPage, Item nextItem)
{
    // Some logic
    return lastItem;
}
```

And let whoever call your method handle the variable.